# How to model a Prisma schema with nested structure and array of strings for a property?

Tags: sql-server, typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm working on modeling a Prisma schema for a product database where each product has a complex structure, including nested properties and an array of strings for image content. Here's an example of the structure I'm aiming for:

```
interface Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
    rating: number;
    category: string;
    retailer: string;
    location: {
        name: string;
        coordinates: {
            longitude: number;
            latitude: number;
        };
    };
    images: {
        thumbnail: string;
        content: string[];
    };
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
}
```

I'm particularly struggling with how to model the images property in my Prisma schema, where content is an array of strings.

Here's what I've attempted so far:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlserver"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}

model Product {
  id          Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  description String
  price       Float
  rating      Float
  category    String
  retailer    String
  location    Location[]
  images      Images[]
  createdAt   DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime   @updatedAt
}

model Images {
  id          Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  thumbnail   String
  content     String
  productId   Int        @unique
  product     Product    @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
}

model Location {
  id          Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  longitude   Float
  latitude    Float
  address     String
  productId   Int        @unique
  product Product        @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
}
```

However, this schema throws an error regarding lists of primitive types not being supported, and this is how close I can get, but it's not the same.

How can I properly model this complex structure in my Prisma schema, ensuring compatibility with a SQL Server database? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting from Prisma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not overly complex - let's dig into it! Removing the primitive data types, we're left with:

```js
interface Product {
  location: {
    name: string;
    coordinates: {
      longitude: number;
      latitude: number;
    };
  };
  images: {
    thumbnail: string;
    content: string[];
  };
}
```

There are some errors in your Prisma schema:

```
model Product {
  id          Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  location    Location[] // location isn't an array in the interface
  images      Images[]   // images isn't an array
}

model Location {
  id          Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  longitude   Float
  latitude    Float
  address     String     // Where did this appear from?
  productId   Int        @unique
  product Product        @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
}
```

IF your interface is correct, here's how to model it in your schema - again, abbreviated to relevant parts:

```
model Product {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  /// Referring to exactly 1 location
  images     Images   @relation(fields: [imagesId], references: [id])
  imagesId   Int
  location   Location @relation(fields: [locationId], references: [id])
  locationId Int
}

model Location {
  id            Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String
  coordinates   Coordinates @relation(fields: [coordinatesId], references: [id])
  coordinatesId Int
  address       String
  productId     Int         @unique
  products      Product[]
}

/// A "helper model" to represent the coordinates of a location
model Coordinates {
  id        Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  longitude Float
  latitude  Float
  locations Location[]
}

model Images {
  id        Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  thumbnail String
  /// One to many relation with ImageContent
  contents  ImageContent[]
  /// Unfortunately, not supported by SQL Server, hence the solution above
  /// contents  String[]
  products  Product[]
}

model ImageContent {
  id       Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  content  String
  images   Images? @relation(fields: [imagesId], references: [id])
  imagesId Int?
}
```

As SQL Server doesn't support string arrays ([source](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/reference/prisma-schema-reference#-modifier)), we have to use a workaround and write an ImageContent model to host content array.

I validated this schema with VS Code + Prisma extension and it should be correct. I **highly** recommend that extension as not only does it validate and format your schema, it can also automatically some of the relations you write.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this has taught me a lot! :)